# How to loop animation with using sleep

Tags: android

My aim is to create a one by one fade animation while the activity is starting , the animation is working fine but it not animating one by one,but it animating all the same time

```
public class Editprofile extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editprofile);

View e=findViewById(R.id.idnameedit);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0.2f, 1f, 0.2f, 1f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        scaleAnimation.setDuration(600);
        ConstraintLayout s=findViewById(R.id.editprofileheadid);
        for(int i=0;i<s.getChildCount();i++){

            s.getChildAt(i).startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
            Thread closeActivity = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(600);
                        Log.d("ticking","ticking");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.getLocalizedMessage();
                    }
                }
            });
            closeActivity.run();

        }
    }


}
```

As you see the above program, the constraint layout contains 5 children when looped its not animation, so I have shifted my code from on **create()** to on Start the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet. Moved the for loop inside the Thread

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0.2f, 1f, 0.2f, 1f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        scaleAnimation.setDuration(600);
        final ConstraintLayout s = findViewById(R.id.editprofileheadid);



        Thread closeActivity = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    for (int i = 0; i < s.getChildCount(); i++) {

                        final int j = i;
                        s.post(
                                new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        s.getChildAt(j).startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
                                    }
                                }
                        );


                    }
                    Thread.sleep(600);
                    Log.d("ticking", "ticking");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getLocalizedMessage();
                }
            }
        });
        closeActivity.run();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `Thread.run` will not run the Runnable on another thread, instead, it runs the runnable at caller's thread. What you want is `Thread.start`

Secondly, you shouldn't call sleep on [MainThread](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#Threads), instead, you can use `postDelayed` to put a callback on message queue which will be executed later.

Sample code:

```java
        ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0.2f, 1f, 0.2f, 1f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        scaleAnimation.setDuration(600);
        ConstraintLayout s=findViewById(R.id.editprofileheadid);
        for(int i=0;i<s.getChildCount();i++){
            s.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    s.getChildAt(i).startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
                }
            }, i * 600);
        }
```

BTW, never manipulate your UI from a worker thread, since Android UI toolkit is not thread-safe.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are the animations not showing? Or they all played at same time?

Comment: No , the animation has changed now , but it is irrelvent to what we are expecting

Comment: What is your expecting animations? Did you forget to set initialize state for views which are waiting for displaying animation? You may need to modify the question to better describe your problem.